# How do I access methods from another file inside module?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Here's a rough structure of a Sinatra API project I'm working on:

- api.rb(main program calling methods on different API endpoints. This is also the project root level of hierarchy)
- methods/v1/auth.rb
- lib/api_helpers.rb

The file auth.rb has code in the following structure:

```
module V1
   require './lib/api_helpers'
end

module V1::Auth

 def register
  do_something #a method defined in api_helpers.rb
 end

end
```

Relevant part of api_helpers.rb :

```
helpers do 
    def do_something
      #lots of blah
    end
end
```

The /register endpoint in api.rb makes a call to `V1::Auth.register`, the file gets invoked **without raising a LoadError** for the api_helpers.rb file required, but throws an `undefined method` error when `do_something` is called.

How do I work in a namespaced structure like this and be able to access methods from files elsewhere in the hierarchy?

Using Ruby 2.3.1

Comment: Hi, show us how you  define `Auth.login_user` method

Comment: Hi @LukasBaliak, sorry about that. I meant a call to Auth.register method and have updated my post accordingly. The method's example skeleton is already included in the code above. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In this case is Method `register` a instance method, so if you wanna to call it like `V1::Auth.register` you must set it like class method.

**EDIT**
You must to add `do_something` to `V1::Auth` module to call it directly.

**api_helpers.rb**

```
def do_something
  puts "I do something"
end
```

**api.rb**

```
module V1
end

module V1::Auth
  require './lib/api_helpers'

  def self.register
    puts "Register"
    do_something
  end
end

V1::Auth.register
# => Register
# => I do something
```

Comment: As I mentioned, the error isn't when invoking Auth.register, but when do_something is called during execution of Auth.register. If I comment out calls to methods defined in api_helpers.rb keeping all else same, Auth.register returns normally without any errors.